# Android Sync ON?

Tags: android, android-emulator, synchronization

I'm using an emulator API 8 and I have a Google account on it. But in Accounts & sync settings I found that 'Sync is OFF'. Is there a chance to turn it ON? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need [install Google Apps](http://senk9.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-install-google-apps-gapps-on-your-android-device-phone/)